# How to select 50 rows everytime from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-limit

I want to select 50 rows every time from a table

I have written following query

```
select * from table order by id asc limit 50 ;
```

Now, I want to select the next 50 records and then the next 50 records.

What query should I write to fetch the next 50 records?

Comment: Hint:  `OFFSET`.

Comment: Hint: `LIMIT 0, 50`  (first 50) `LIMIT 50, 50` (next 50)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `offset` clause to specify where the return value would start. E.g., in the first run:

```
select * from table order by id asc limit 50 offset 0; -- Returns rows 1-50
```

And then:

```
select * from table order by id asc limit 50 offset 50; -- Returns rows 50-100
```

And so on.